# Progress 4GL- Sending Zip file containing NULL characters from Memptr to XML node?

Tags: xml, null, zip, openedge, progress-4gl

Progress 4GL- I have to send zip file from memory pointer to XML. Zip file contains NULL character.while storing zip file from memptr to xml node using MEMPTR-TO-NODE, it is eliminating NULL character.So zip file gets corrupted and can't be unzipped. Is there any other approach to do this?
TIA.

Comment: If you post your code (even non functional) it will be easier to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use base64 encoded binary data using the BASE64-ENCODE function.

```
h-your-node-ref:LONGCHAR-TO-NODE-VALUE (BASE64-ENCODE (m-your-memptr)).
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add an example of how to encode with BASE64-ENCODE?

Comment: Thanks Mike! The requirement is to do both base64 encoding and zip. So this flow works! "file -> zip -> base64"